# how to implement robust row filtering (by user) for Breeze+WebAPI+EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I need to have all access to particular entities limited by the logged-in user's identity (they can only see certain instances, based upon complex rules). It is too difficult to specify in oData $filter (I wouldn't want to do it that way regardless). I don't want to resort to repositories (I am trying to provide the fullest featured, most flexible data interface possible for a dynamic responsive web app). I would like to intercept the request at some point in the Microsoft (or Breeze) stack to modify the oData query or the EntityFramework query to inject the security filtration. I know how to do it easily for direct requests for the entities, but I want it to also work when requested indirectly (via navigation properties from related entities). Ideas?

Comment: only do security based on the authenticated user. Dont do it based on the data they post. You can post ANY data your like. eg fiddler . So that means repository pattern / EF layer and and a filter (where restriction) to selected records.

Answer (score 0):

Queries that are the result of entity navigation loads are actually just regular queries against the "defaultResourceName" for each type.  So as long as you gate all of your "default" endpoints ( as it sounds like you are already doing for direct requests), you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Entity Framework 6](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=specs) you could use the [IDBCommandInterceptor](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interception) interface to intercept all database commands at the lowest level.

[Entity Framework Logging and Intercepting Database Operations (EF6 Onwards)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464)